# SQL: Select users where relationship count == 1

Tags: sql

Using Postgres.

I have users, which have items.  Items have a column "type."  I'm trying to get a list of users, that have items, whose item types are not null, and the count of these "not null" items is exactly 1.

Desired query:

```
select *
from users
join items
where items.type IS NOT NULL
and the count of (items.type IS NOT NULL) == 1
```

Let me know if there's any more information I can provide.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a cartesian product there; you are not specifying how the users and the items table join. I know this is not your question, but before one can answer your question, you need to tell us how to join those two tables

Comment: do you need all the columns from both tables?

Comment: Once the brain mush has subsided, perhaps you can add a bit more to your question...?

Comment: What is the relationship between user and items?

Comment: I edited the question to provide more information. To whomever gave me a "-1" --> if the new level of detail is sufficient, please remove your downgrade. If it's not sufficient, please let me know what other information I can provide.

Comment: @BlackTigerX - nope, I don't need all the columns.  A users.id would suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select users.id, count(items.type)
from users
join items on items.user_id = user.id
where items.type IS NOT NULL
group by users.id
having count(items.type) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your dialect -- you need to relate your two tables.  Either:

```
table a JOIN table b on some field(s)
```

OR

```
WHERE some fields in table a = some field(s) in table b
```

Also -- consider how you relate the tables -- exact match, all a and only matching b, etc.